# requests.post mangles dictionary data, how to do it right?

Tags: php, python

given request_test.py (copy and paste of one example at the official requests docs http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

```
import requests
payload = {'key1': ['value1', 'value2']}
r = requests.post('http://localhost/testserv/test.php', data = payload)
```

and test.php

```
<?php
ob_flush();
ob_start();
var_dump($_POST);
file_put_contents("dump.txt", ob_get_flush());
```

when i run the script the dump.txt content is

```
array(1) {
    ["key1"]=>
    string(6) "value2"
}
```

the question is, how do i send non basic variables with a post requests using the requests module?

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be in Python but rather the response object.

Comment: i'm not even looking at the response (php isnt doing anything except dumping txt to a file), php is just receiving wrong values